# Adding a class to a checkbox, upon checking

Tags: vuejs2

My data:

```
products: {
    'price': [],
    'in_stock': [],
},
```

I have some checkboxes that operate on the same model:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="price-0" value="0" v-model="products.price">
 <label for="price-0">Studio</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="price-1" value="1" v-model="products.price">
 <label for="price-1">Studio</label>
 ....
```

Upon checking (and unchecking), how can I add/remove a class  to the checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. If you are rendering your inputs in a v-for loop then it would be quite simple to do something like `item.id`  to replace each instance of `data-0` `data-1` etc.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/jyak7jz1/) also if you want to play with the code.

```js
Vue.component('my-cool-component', {
 template: '#cool',
  data(){
   return{
     products: {
      'price': [],
      'in_stock': [],
        },
       isChk: [],
    }
  },
  methods:{
   select(id){
          this.isChk.includes(id) ?  this.isChk.splice(this.isChk.indexOf(id), 1) : this.isChk.push(id)
      }
  }
});


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
.checked {
  color: #fff;
  background: #f82c00;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.output {
  padding: 1px 15px;
  background: #413e3e;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 23px 5px;
  border-radius: 6px
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <my-cool-component></my-cool-component>
</div>

<template id="cool">
  <div id="wapper">
    <input
         id="price-0"
         type="checkbox"
         value="0"
         v-model="products.price" 
         @click="select('price-0')"
    >
    <label :class="{checked:isChk.includes('price-0')}" for="price-0">Studio</label>
    
    <input 
         id="price-1"
         type="checkbox"  
         value="1"
         v-model="products.price" 
         @click="select('price-1')">
     <label :class="{checked:isChk.includes('price-1')}"  for="price-1">Studio</label>
     
     <div class="output">
       <p>price -- {{products.price}}</p>
       <p>is checked -- {{isChk}}</p>
     </div>  
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, it is preferred to handle dynamic styles in a declarative way. Doing so you leverage the sweet reactive style binding which automatically updates them accordingly on data changes.

Something like this will do it:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="price-0" value="0" v-model="products.price" :class="{'checked-class' : products.price === 0}">
 <label for="price-0">Studio</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="price-1" value="1" v-model="products.price"
    :class="{'checked-class' : products.price === 1}">
 <label for="price-1">Studio</label>
```

Reference:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html